# How to apply Nginx Ingress rate limiting?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress, nginx-config

I am trying to implement rate limiting feature to my AKS using nginx ingress rate limiting. I have just provided `limit-rps:10` in nginx ingress resource. Still, i dont see expected behavior which is rps * default burst rate. Could somebody help on how rate limiting works in nginx and how to set the configuration in nginx resource?

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"kubernetes.io/ingress.class":"nginx","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rpm":"1","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size":"30m","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target":"/$2","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect":"false"},"name":"hop-ingress","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"rules":[{"http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"example-service","servicePort":80},"path":"/"}]}}]}}
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-connections: "1"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps: "1"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 30m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
  creationTimestamp: "2021-08-13T13:33:12Z"
  generation: 2
  name: hop-ingress
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "21201898"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/hop-ingress
  uid: 574f4cf5-6b66-414f-ba2c-3c36c9d62ef0
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: example-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: productpage
          servicePort: 9080
        path: /productpage(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 13.71.57.131
```

Answer (score 3):

`limit-rps` is a [local rate limit settings](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rate-limiting) that is applied on a specific ingress object rather than in a config map provided to the ingress controller.

It will limit the number of requests per second from an IP adress:

> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps: number of requests accepted
> from a given IP each second. The burst limit is set to this limit
> multiplied by the burst multiplier, the default multiplier is 5. When
> clients exceed this limit, limit-req-status-code default: 503 is
> returned.

Please se below for a dummy example. As you can see `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps: 10` is added under `metadata.annotations` on the ingress object

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps: 10
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:
              number: 80
```

It is possible to apply [global rate limiting](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#global-rate-limiting) as well, please see the manual for details

Comment: @danielorn- Thanks for your response!!!!I have implemented above local rate limiting. I have setup limit-rps: 1  .As per my understanding ingress should reject request if request limit exceeds more than 5/sec. I am not getting 503 http code as threshold got increased.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the yaml for the ingress object where you expect rate limiting?

Comment: It must be 5 requests per second from the same IP, otherwise it will not kick in.